# Evaluating Expression program trouble taking user input

Tags: java, arrays, stack, program-entry-point, args

A lot of this code is already written but the code that I have added was to include ^ and %. It is the code to evaluate an expression in the right order using stacks. What I'm having trouble with this is the main method and adding a way to take user input and print out the result of the problem. I'm just including that part of the code

```
16 import java.util.Stack;
17 import java.util.Scanner;
18 
19 public class EvaluateExpression {
20  public static void main(String[] args) {
21       
22      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
23      System.out.println("Enter the expression to be evaluated: ");
24      String expression = input.nextLine();
25      
26      //Check number of arguments passed
27      if (args.length != 1) {
28          System.out.println("Usage: java EvaluateExpression \"expression\"");
29          System.exit(1);
30      }
31      try {
32          System.out.println(expression + " = " + 
33                  evaluateExpression(expression));
34      }
35      catch (Exception ex) {
36          ex.printStackTrace();
37          System.out.println("Wrong expression: " + expression);
38      }
39      
40  }
```

Expected results: it is printing the expression to be evaluated along with the results.
But here is what I am getting with this when I try to enter a random expression:

Enter the expression to be evaluated:

6+9*8-7

Usage: java EvaluateExpression "expression"

Comment: You aren't passing any parameters into your program via the command line, so `if (args.length != 1)` returns `true` and exits the program.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that args.length is different than 1.

Comment: I thought so, so I need to add the expression to args in order for it to evaluate it correct? I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that. I've tried replacing expression with args[0] but I'm sure that is the wrong way of doing it. Sorry I am still very new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is reading from standard input. Don't need to check args count. Args is program arguments that direct input of your program. Like 
`ls *.txt`
or 
`java -cp . EvaluateExpression <myvalue>`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried taking this part of the program out and if I do that it prints the " Wrong expression: " + expression portion.

Comment: Do you get expression from scanner as expected? Probably evaluateExpression method  throws an exception.

Comment: If I take that portion out it gives me error java.util.EmptyStackException and prints "Wrong expression: " + expression message.

Comment: Print expression and evaluate result on separate lines. Like ```System.out.print(expression + " = ");
System.out.println(evaluateExpression(expression));```

Comment: And debug your program to be sure to read input properly.  I suppose that you are getting exception from evaluateExpression method.

Comment: Okay, I added that and took out the "ex.printStackTrace();" and now am getting "Enter the expression to be evaluated: 
6+8-4
6+8-4 = 
Wrong expression: 6+8-4"

Comment: Obviously you are getting exception from evaluateExpression method.